# How to fix AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'?

Tags: python, pytorch

Today i faced with problem
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'`
I read a data from csv file with 2 columns: Image (where the file path is) and finding (where the photo's label is)
Model:

```
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=False)
model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, 256),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Dropout(p=0.3),
                         nn.Linear(256, 100),
                         nn.ReLU(),
                         nn.Dropout(p=0.4),
                         nn.Linear(100,9))
# model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model.pth'))

for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if("bn" not in name):
        param.requires_grad = False
```

Transforms:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5457, 0.5457, 0.5457], std=[0.2342, 0.2342, 0.2342])    
])
```

Dataset class:

```
class Col(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv, main_dir, transform):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(csv)
        self.main_dir = main_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return self.df.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = transform(Image.open(self.df.Image[idx]).convert("RGB"))
        label = self.df.Finding[idx]
        return image, label
```

Prepairing Data:

```
data = Col(main_dir=root_dir,csv=csv_file, transform=transform)
dataset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=130)
train_set, validate_set= torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [round(len(dataset)*0.7), (len(dataset) - round(len(dataset)*0.7))])
```

Train func:

```
def train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, train_set, validate_set, epochs=20, device="cpu"):
    for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
        training_loss = 0.0
        valid_loss = 0.0
        model.train()
        for batch in train_set:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            inputs, labels = batch
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            output = model(inputs)
            loss = loss_fn(output, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            training_loss += loss.data.item() * inputs.size(0)
        training_loss /= len(train_set.dataset)
        
        model.eval()
        num_correct = 0 
        num_examples = 0
        for batch in validate_set:
            inputs, labels = batch
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            output = model(inputs)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            loss = loss_fn(output, labels) 
            valid_loss += loss.data.item() * inputs.size(0)
            correct = torch.eq(torch.max(F.softmax(output, dim=1), dim=1)[1], targets)
            num_correct += torch.sum(correct).item()
            num_examples += correct.shape[0]
        valid_loss /= len(validate_set.dataset)

        print('Epoch: {}, Training Loss: {:.2f}, Validation Loss: {:.2f}, accuracy = {:.2f}'.format(epoch, training_loss,
        valid_loss, num_correct / num_examples))
```

Optimazer:

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
```

After calling train func

```
train(model, optimizer,torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), train_set.dataset, validate_set.dataset, epochs=100, device=device)
```

I've got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_9156/634509595.py in <module>
----> 1 train(model, optimizer,torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), train_set.dataset, validate_set.dataset, epochs=100, device=device)

/tmp/ipykernel_9156/2858123881.py in train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, train_set, validate_set, epochs, device)
      8             inputs, labels = batch
      9             inputs = inputs.to(device)
---> 10             labels = labels.to(device)
     11             output = model(inputs)
     12             loss = loss_fn(output, labels)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'
```

If i try to call this

```
for batch in train_set.dataset:
    inputs, labels = batch
    print(labels)
```

then it will display many large tuples with labels.(like this)

```
('polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps', 'polyps')
```

How can i fix this? Help me please

Comment: What is confusing about the error? Did you read it? What makes you think that tuples have the attribute `.to()`?

Comment: Yes, I read about it and spent a whole day on it (before asking a question here). I know this may sound like a silly question, but how do I convert these tuples to regular strings and then to Tensor?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert these tuples to regular strings?"

Comment: I mean get all the labels out of the tuples
Or use a function from Pandas that will return strings rather than tuples

P.S. the word "regular" was superfluous, sorry for this and other mistakes

Comment: What is the `'polyps'` label, is it a class? If so how many classes do you have? `9`?

Comment: Yes, 'polyps' is the name of the class. And you are right, there are only 9. In the csv file itself, they are repeated many times (some even a thousand) and each corresponds to the path to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your labels into integers (or one-hot encodings depending on your `loss_fn`).

You should have `classes`, a *list* of *9* class names. If not you can get it with `self.df.Finding.unique()`.

You can then invert this *list* into a *dictionnary*, essentially a `label-name -> label-id` mapping:

```
self.encode = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(classes)}
```

Then in your dataset `__getitem__` definition convert the label names to label ids with `encode`:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    image = transform(Image.open(self.df.Image[idx]).convert("RGB"))
    label = self.encode[self.df.Finding[idx]]
    return image, label
```

Comment: I did everything as you said, but I got an error `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: I tried using square brackets in `self.encode(i)`, but it raised `KeyError: 'p'`

Comment: Yes. It shows a dictionary where the keys are numbers from 0 to 8 and each contains a class

Comment: It should be the inverse: keys are label names and values are integers. Can you show the content of `self.df.Finding.unique()`?

Comment: `['polyps' 'ulcerative-colitis-grade-1' 'ulcerative-colitis-grade-2'
 'ulcerative-colitis-grade-3' 'impacted-stool' 'dyed-lifted-polyps'
 'dyed-resection-margins' 'barretts' 'esophagitis']`

Comment: And print(self.encode): `{'polyps': 0, 'ulcerative-colitis-grade-1': 1, 'ulcerative-colitis-grade-2': 2, 'ulcerative-colitis-grade-3': 3, 'impacted-stool': 4, 'dyed-lifted-polyps': 5, 'dyed-resection-margins': 6, 'barretts': 7, 'esophagitis': 8}`

Comment: And `self.df.Finding[idx]` returns a tuple of label names, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's returns a tuple.

Comment: Try `label = self.encode[self.df.Finding[idx]]` instead.